# Using e.keyCode || e.which; how to determine the difference between lowercase and uppercase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am using `e.keyCode || e.which;` to determine which key was pressed, but I am getting 65 for both <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> why is this happening and how can I detect the difference between the two?

Comment: Key ≠ character.

Comment: +1, May i ask for an elaboration?

Comment: Quite simple: not every key corresponds to a character. Some examples of non-character keys are the arrow keys. Or Control, Alt and Shift. Or the function keys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just use `e.which` in jquery. They normalize this value for all browsers.

Additionally you can check for `e.shiftKey`.

Comment: Be aware that (at least in v1.7.1) this is not true for keypress - e.which will be 0 for most keys - but it will work for keydown.

Comment: @Synexis can you provide a source link? I do not see this behavior in 1.9.1.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it's 'a' or 'A', 65 is the result of the key pressed on the keyboard and it's always 65 for that key.

The event will only specify which key is pressed and not its value; those are two separate things.  You can test for event.shiftKey along with the key that you're looking for, but I don't believe that will handle the scenario where Caps Lock is enabled.

Comment: That's only true of `keydown` and `keyup` events. `keypress` gives you information about the character typed.

Answer (score 0):

This script is useful for small and capital letters press

```
<form>
    Char: <input type="text" id="char" size="15" /> Keycode: <input type="text" id="unicode" size="15" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var charfield=document.getElementById("char")
    charfield.onkeypress=function(e){
    var e=window.event || e
    var keyunicode=e.charCode || e.keyCode
    document.getElementById("unicode").value=keyunicode
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: This will yield the uppercase letter, even if lowercase was entered.

Answer (score 0):

This is spectacularly cross-browser-broken in vanilla JavaScript, which is why you should use Josiah Ruddell's solution.  See [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) for more than you want to know.

Comment: It's broken but not in a hugely complicated way. jQuery's normalization is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

keyCode won't indicate which character was input.
To truly find the character last entered by the user you will need to examine the value of the input and find the last character.