# how to track when user presses enter on a drop down list option with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML form with a drop down list. I want to get the selected drop down value when the user select an option by arrow keys and presses enter key on one of the drop down options

HTML code:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

When the user selects `Mercedes` and presses enter I want to get that value. I can get that value by

```
$('option').live('click',function(){

var text = $(this)

});
```

but I want to get it when they press the `enter` key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/fFYuD/1/) is a working example.

```
$('select').live('keypress',function(e){
    var key = e.which;
    if(key == 13)// the enter key code
        {
            // do your thing
        }
});
```

As [oezi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288773/oezi) said, you might be looking for the change event, but if you really want to capture the enter keypress, this is the way to do it.

Comment: seems like K.B Panamaldeniya-littletipz simply doesn't know about the existence of `.change()`, wich seems to be exactly what he's looking for. i don't think we should lead him to a solution, that (maybe) works but can be replaces with a way better solution.

Comment: I almost lost my hope. And, fortunately saw this example. *Great Work.* Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution please try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<select id="ddlDemo">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<script>



$('#ddlDemo').keyup(function(event) {
if(event.which==13)
{
  var text = $(this).val();
  alert(text);
}

});

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you're looking for is the `change`-event:

```
$('select').change(function(){

  var text = $(this).val();
  // whatever to do here

});
```

or, using `.live()` (if this is neccessary for you):

```
$('select').live('change',function(){

  var text = $(this).val();
  // whatever to do here

});
```

for more information, take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

PS: you shouldn't bind events to the `option`s, the `select` is the form-element and should be used to bind events on.

**EDIT:** added an example for `live()`, thanks to pyvi for the hint.

Comment: so take a look at the documentation-link i've given and check what could be wrong with your code - maybe you have another problem with the code inside of the change-event. what do you do with `text`? are there any other events bound on the `select` or it's `option`s that can cause the problem? do you get any error-messages? some more information would be really useful...

Comment: The live function pretty much just needs to be changed to bind "change" and not "click". See http://jsfiddle.net/z9q8Z/3/

Answer (score 0):

The change event is probably the right way to go here. However, if you ever need something to work only on pressing enter, here is an example:

```
$('select').live('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var text = $(this)
    }
});
```

13 is the keycode for the enter key.

http://jsfiddle.net/z9q8Z/2/

Comment: -1 exactly what gion_13 wrote almost 6 minutes ago (and he used `e.which`, which is what should be used with jquery because of cross-browser compatibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401305/using-e-keycode-e-which-how-to-determine-the-differance-between-lowercase-and/4401321#4401321)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following JQuery script and it works with me.

```
$("#ddlName").keypress(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;

    if (key === 13)// the enter key code
    {
        // Handle enter key
    }
});
```