# Actual key assigned to JavaScript keyCode

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have setup an event listener:

```
editor.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey === false) {
        alert(String.charFromCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase());
    }
    else {
        alert(String.charFromCode(e.keyCode));
    }
}, false);
```

When the user presses <kbd>2</kbd> along with <kbd>shift</kbd>, how do I know if I should output (@) or (")? Each users' character mapping is different per locale.

Comment: Tim Down's comment is the solution in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401305/using-e-keycode-e-which-how-to-determine-the-differance-between-lowercase-and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `keypress` event instead. It will reliably (barring a few edge cases) detect the character typed.

There are a few browser oddities (such as some non-printable keys generating `keypress` events with key codes in the `which` property in some browsers) that prevent the following example from being 100% perfect which you can read about in great detail at [the definitive page on JavaScript key events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html).

Example:

```
editor.addEventListener('keypress',
function(e)
{
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    alert( String.charFromCode(charCode) );
},
false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you really can't. Use a `keypress` or `keyup` listener, and compare the old (textbox, I assume?) value to the new one to see what actually happened.

Comment: You might want to explain what bigger problem you're trying to solve, since there's probably a solution to it already.

Comment: I've updated a little bit the code. I want to figure out how am i going to get the correct keyCode, since javascript returns the same keyCode for both KEY and KEY+SHIFT.

Comment: Then I would suggest **not** looking at individual keystrokes. Sure, you can update the highlighting after a keystroke, but it's hellish to do things the way you're trying. Also, you're returning a string from the event handler, why?

Comment: Sorry about the returns, corrected it. Why do you think it's hellish? If i had a <textarea> i wouldn't be able to colorize text. So what I'm trying to do is to listen to individual keystrokes inside a div with "tabindex" set, so i can <pre> lines, and <span> colorize individual words. You happen to know an easier way?

Comment: The `keypress` event **can** be used to extract the character typed reliably. It's fundamentally different from `keydown` and `keyup` in that it's concerned with the character typed, while the others are concerned with detecting the actual key.