# Cross Browser issue with Keyup Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function numbersonly(e){
var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode
if (unicode!=8){ //if the key isn't the backspace key (which we should allow)
if (unicode<65||unicode>90) //if not a Capital Alphabet
return false //disable key press
}
}
</script>

<form>
<input type="text" size=18 onkeyup="return numbersonly(event)">
</form>
```

This code is working fine. But IE doesn't support charcode. and In Keycode, 65 to 90 range includes both capital and lower case letters. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: 65 to 90 range includes both capital and lower case letters ?? lower case starts from 97

Comment: That is for charcode.I'm referring to KeyCode.

Comment: Is the charcode and keycode both same or different?

Comment: Try `e.shiftKey` to see if the shift key was pressed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It will not handled by the simple one you have to check many conditions in that `case` like,

**Checking caps lock on or not**

Use this function for this,

```
function isCapslock(e){

    e = (e) ? e : window.event;

    var charCode = false;
    if (e.which) {
        charCode = e.which;
    } else if (e.keyCode) {
        charCode = e.keyCode;
    }

    var shifton = false;
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        shifton = e.shiftKey;
    } else if (e.modifiers) {
        shifton = !!(e.modifiers & 4);
    }

    if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122 && shifton) {
        return true;
    }

    if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90 && !shifton) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Refered from http://dougalmatthews.com/articles/2008/jul/2/javascript-detecting-caps-lock/

**Additionally**

just use `e.which` in jquery. They normalize this value for all browsers.

Additionally you can check for `e.shiftKey`.

Source [Using e.keyCode || e.which; how to determine the differance between lowercase and uppercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401305/using-e-keycode-e-which-how-to-determine-the-differance-between-lowercase-an)

Comment: Can we use e.which in Javascript. do javascript also  normalize this value for all browsers.?