# what is the difference between e.keyCode and e.which?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)** in this when I try `e.keyCode` For enter key like below

```
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
// my code
    }
```

then it works with ie7 and all major browsers but not in ie10.

But when I use `e.which` it runs in all major browsers.

What  is the difference between `e.keyCode` and `e.which`?

Comment: [jQuery normalizes this all](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401305/using-e-keycode-e-which-how-to-determine-the-differance-between-lowercase-an

Comment: i am using like $('#term').keyup(function(e) {
                       if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                            //$('#searchExpert').click();
                            return false;
                            }
                        });

Comment: thanks @Balus it is useful for me

Comment: thanks @LaurentG it is useful for me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode.
>   It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.

As per [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

keyCode is standard JavaScript and of course not implemented in the same way by all browsers.

Comment: thanks it works +1 up for that ..:)